# Flatten rows of a 2d array so that values become keys and row indexes become values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, flatten, flip

I have an array like this:

```
[
    ["a", "b"]
    ["c", "d"]
]
```

I want to convert it into:

```
[
    'a' => '0',
    'b' => '0',
    'c' => '1',
    'd' => '1',
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Better way than what? show us what you have tried. - Also, can't you do this as you generate the array? - And just to be sure, you want to turn the multidimensional array into a flat array right?

Comment: each value from nested array becomes a key and should have the initial parent key as a value, right?

Comment: Better way, Means fast way. ya it should be flat array, but with flip, means old array key should be new array value and old array value should be new array key.

Comment: ya eaxctly  RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use nested loop.

```
foreach($array as $k => $arr) {
   foreach($arr as $v) {
      $result[$v] = $k;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
 [a] => 0
 [b] => 0
 [c] => 1
 [d] => 1
)
```

Comment: But it will take much when array is large. Is there any array function we can use to get this result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `array_fill_keys`, `array_merge`

```
<?php
$test = [0=> array("a","b"),1=> array("c","d")];
$retest = array();
foreach($test as $key=>&$value){
  $value = array_fill_keys($value, $key);
  $retest = array_merge($retest,$value);
}
print_r($retest);
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/604948

Output is :

```
    Array
(
    [a] => 0
    [b] => 0
    [c] => 1
    [d] => 1
)
```

Comment: Your eval.in link did not load for me.  Also, the code works just as well without a reference variable.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `array_values`, `array_fill_keys` and `array_merge` functions:

```
$arr = [
  ['a','b'],
  ['c','d'],
  ['e','f'],
];

$flipped = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $flipped = array_merge($flipped, array_fill_keys(array_values($v), $k));
}

print_r($flipped);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 0
    [b] => 0
    [c] => 1
    [d] => 1
    [e] => 2
    [f] => 2
)
```

Comment: $arr = [
  ['a','b'],
  ['c','d'],
  ['e','f'],
];

Comment: @SunilPrajapati, I've presented an extended array. Your array is `[ ['a','b'], ['c','d'] ];`. It should work fine. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional style approach:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EKEa3))

```
var_export(
    array_merge(
        ...array_map(
            'array_fill_keys',
            $arr,
            array_keys($arr)
        )
    )
);
```

This maps the values from the subarrays to the parent keys, then flattens the multi-dimensional structure into the desired flat, associative structure.

This technique does not make iterated calls of `array_merge()`; it only calls `array_merge()` once after `array_map()` is finished iterating.